# looking forward to use toggle_hide_show method in my code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I have JSON file, which has few payloads. The requirement was once i submit order number in the search bar and hit enter, all the payloads should appear as tables. i have done it with our Stackoverflow community. But Also i need to show each payload like ""how_js_toggle_hide_show"" method. means, once i click on each payload, the details should appear just below each line and in another click it should hide too.

here is my JS :

```
var data = [{
    "eventInfo": {
      "context": {
        "siteTimezone": "Asia/Brunei",
        "entityPk": "8802089762861",
        "entityClass": "de.hybris.platform.core.model.order.OrderModel",
        "com.amway.core.events.model.AmwayEventQueueEntryModel": "8805563195834"
      },
      "isoCountryCode": "BN",
      "eventType": "ORDER_CONFIRMED",
      "entityType": "salesorder",
      "sourceTimestamp": "2020-06-25T14:05:56.683+08:00",
      "sourceApplication": "HYBRIS",
      "affiliateCode": "100",
      "entityId": "7100029639",
      "sourceEventId": "4521231e-c347-459b-8d46-43cd2010c8c1",
      "accountId": "8055817",
      "sourceHost": "ip-10-127-165-135.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal"
    },
    "entity": {
      "lynxIsPCP": false,
      "paymentRequired": true,
      "bonusTransactionRequired": true,
      "addresses": [{
          "telephoneNumber": "03-7946 2800",
          "isoCountryCode": "BN",
          "line3": "Bandar Seri Begawan",
          "cityName": "Brunei",
          "line2": "Kampung Kiulap",
          "line1": "6 & 7, Block A, Kompleks Shakirin",
          "careOfName": "",
          "state": "BR",
          "emailAddress": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
          "postalCode": "BE1518",
          "id": "8804188225559"
        },
        {
          "telephoneNumber": "5494492",
          "isoCountryCode": "BN",
          "line3": "GADONG",
          "line4": "8171571",
          "cityName": "BDR SERI BEGAWAN",
          "line2": "KAMPONG RIMBA",
          "line1": "5 SIMPANG 12-32",
          "careOfName": "",
          "state": "BR",
          "emailAddress": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
          "postalCode": "BE3119",
          "id": "8802223521815"
        },
        {
          "telephoneNumber": "5494492",
          "isoCountryCode": "BN",
          "line3": "GADONG",
          "line4": "8171571",
          "cityName": "BDR SERI BEGAWAN",
          "line2": "KAMPONG RIMBA",
          "line1": "5 SIMPANG 12-32",
          "careOfName": "",
          "state": "BR",
          "emailAddress": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
          "postalCode": "BE3119",
          "id": "8802223521815"
        },
        {
          "telephoneNumber": "03-7946 2800",
          "isoCountryCode": "BN",
          "line3": "Bandar Seri Begawan",
          "cityName": "Brunei",
          "line2": "Kampung Kiulap",
          "line1": "6 & 7, Block A, Kompleks Shakirin",
          "careOfName": "",
          "state": "BR",
          "emailAddress": "myhelpdesk@Amway.com",
          "postalCode": "BE1518",
          "id": "8800157073431"
        }
      ],
      "totalOrderValue": 147.5,
      "lynxPaymentChangePaid": 0.0,
      "lynxIsRepair": false,
      "adjustments": [],
      "requestedDeliveryServiceLevel": "walkin",
      "lynxTenure": 0,
      "saleCountryCode": "BN",
      "orderDateTime": "2020-06-25T14:05:56.328+08:00",
      "invoiceSalesAccount": {
        "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
        "accountId": "8055817",
        "lynxPinLevel": "330",
        "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
        "affiliateCode": "100"
      },
      "userAgent": "Suresh Mathiarasu",
      "orderStatus": "CONFIRMED",
      "isoCurrencyCode": "BND",
      "fees": [{
        "feeCode": "walkin",
        "feeTaxTotalAmount": 0.0,
        "lynxRefunded": false,
        "feeAmount": 0.0,
        "feeTaxDetails": [{
          "taxAmount": 0.0,
          "taxCode": "BN_NO_SCOPE_VAT_SALES"
        }]
      }],
      "bonusPeriod": "202006",
      "orderingPartyId": "40986385",
      "lynxPayerPartyId": "40986385",
      "salesChannelCode": "Point of Sale",
      "lynxIsEpp": false,
      "lynxPayerPartyName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP",
      "lynxDemandLocationName": "BN",
      "lynxDeliveryType": "pis",
      "paymentSalesAccount": {
        "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
        "accountId": "8055817",
        "lynxPinLevel": "330",
        "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
        "affiliateCode": "100"
      },
      "orderPriceList": "AmwayDefaultABOPriceGroup",
      "lynxVolumePartyId": "40986385",
      "lynxHasSopEntries": false,
      "orderLines": [{
        "linePrice": 147.5,
        "itemType": "AmwayVariantProduct",
        "itemBV": 29.5,
        "lynxBirTaxPerUnit": 0.0,
        "lynxInvoiceNumber": "130099000",
        "lynxLineAdjustedPV": 0.0,
        "shippedQuantity": 0,
        "lineStatus": "OPEN",
        "lynxProductSerialNumber": [],
        "lineUnitOfMeasure": "EA",
        "allocatedQuantity": 5,
        "linePVAmount": 95.0,
        "lynxBmCode": [],
        "lastUpdateDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:56.469+08:00",
        "lynxBillingAddressReference": "8802223521815",
        "cancelledQuantity": 0,
        "lynxBaseItemId": "115383D",
        "demandLocation": "T45",
        "backorderedQuantity": 0,
        "taxNotRequired": false,
        "pickupAddressReference": "8804188225559",
        "unallocatedQuantity": 0,
        "pendingQuantity": 5,
        "itemABOPrice": 29.5,
        "lineTaxTotalAmount": 0.0,
        "lynxIsSopLine": false,
        "lynxWasBackorder": false,
        "itemSuggestedRetailPrice": 37.0,
        "lineTotalValue": 147.5,
        "baseItemId": "115383D",
        "lynxMasterCode": [],
        "itemDescription": "ARTISTRY SIGNATURE COLOR Lipstick - Daring Red (06) (3.8g)",
        "lineTaxDetails": [{
          "taxAmount": 0.0,
          "taxCode": "BN_NO_SCOPE_VAT_SALES"
        }],
        "shipAddressReference": "8804188225559",
        "lynxPickupAddressName": "BN",
        "lynxIsSopEntry": false,
        "lynxBirAcknowledgementResetCounter": "1",
        "lynxLineAdjustedBV": 0.0,
        "orderedQuantity": 5,
        "itemListPrice": 29.5,
        "fulfillmentType": "walkin",
        "returnedQuantity": 0,
        "orderLineId": 0,
        "itemPV": 19.0,
        "lineBVAmount": 147.5
      }],
      "lynxFulfillmentAddressReference": "8800157073431",
      "cashierBatchId": "amwaybrunei-AM-BN-BN-T45-MY020394-1593058911313",
      "lynxOrderingPartyName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP",
      "totalBVAmount": 147.5,
      "lynxVolumeTransactions": [],
      "volumeSalesAccount": {
        "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
        "accountId": "8055817",
        "lynxPinLevel": "330",
        "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
        "affiliateCode": "100"
      },
      "taxDetails": [{
        "taxAmount": 0.0,
        "taxCode": "BN_NO_SCOPE_VAT_SALES"
      }],
      "lynxUserType": "AmwayBusinessNature_1",
      "lynxPaymentTenderedAmount": 147.5,
      "lynxVolumePartyName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP",
      "lynxOrderCreatedBy": "MY020394",
      "lynxOms": "Hybris",
      "orderForSalesAccount": {
        "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
        "accountId": "8055817",
        "lynxPinLevel": "330",
        "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
        "affiliateCode": "100"
      },
      "lynxPaymentInstalmentType": "PIF",
      "lynxMemberPoints": 0.0,
      "lynxContactPhone": "5494492",
      "totalPVAmount": 95.0,
      "inventoryTransactionRequired": true,
      "lynxIsEventBooking": false,
      "lynxBirCashierId": "MY020394",
      "refunds": [],
      "invoiceWithConsignmentRequired": false,
      "orderPeriod": "202006",
      "orderingSalesAccount": {
        "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
        "accountId": "8055817",
        "lynxPinLevel": "330",
        "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
        "affiliateCode": "100"
      },
      "lynxContactEmailId": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
      "amwaySalesEntity": "780",
      "paymentStatus": "PAID",
      "storefront": "amwaybrunei",
      "lynxPaymentType": "PIF",
      "salesOrderId": "7100029639",
      "lynxOrderCategory": "selfOrder",
      "payments": [{
        "verificationDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:54.453+08:00",
        "lynxIsConnectedFlow": false,
        "paymentLocation": "T45",
        "lynxPaymentProcessedBy": "8055817",
        "paymentStatus": "ACCEPTED",
        "terminalId": "MY020394",
        "paymentReferenceId": "TXN-1593065154321",
        "payerSalesAccount": {
          "accountId": "8055817",
          "lynxPinLevel": "330",
          "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
          "affiliateCode": "100"
        },
        "paymentDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:54.456+08:00",
        "isoCurrencyCode": "BND",
        "lynxPaymentInformation": "",
        "paymentId": "831122002_4e7c1945-b49d-4c86-a0b8-a05b0cb805fa",
        "paymentValue": 147.5,
        "paymentMethod": "cash",
        "merchantId": "amway"
      }],
      "shipToSalesAccount": {
        "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
        "accountId": "8055817",
        "lynxPinLevel": "330",
        "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
        "affiliateCode": "100"
      },
      "totalABORetailProfit": 0.0,
      "totalTaxAmount": 0.0,
      "lynxOrderType": "NORMAL_ORDER",
      "lynxComments": []
    }
  },
  {
    "eventInfo": {
      "context": {
        "siteTimezone": "Asia/Brunei",
        "entityPk": "8802089762861",
        "entityClass": "de.hybris.platform.core.model.order.OrderModel",
        "com.amway.core.events.model.AmwayEventQueueEntryModel": "8805597503930"
      },
      "isoCountryCode": "BN",
      "eventType": "LYNX_ORDER_UPDATE",
      "entityType": "salesorder",
      "sourceTimestamp": "2020-06-25T14:05:57.250+08:00",
      "sourceApplication": "HYBRIS",
      "affiliateCode": "100",
      "entityId": "7100029639",
      "sourceEventId": "8ab538d6-e525-4c8d-b1cf-411d562715f8",
      "accountId": "8055817",
      "sourceHost": "ip-10-127-165-86.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal"
    },
    "entity": {
      "lynxIsPCP": false,
      "paymentRequired": true,
      "bonusTransactionRequired": true,
      "addresses": [{
          "telephoneNumber": "03-7946 2800",
          "isoCountryCode": "BN",
          "line3": "Bandar Seri Begawan",
          "cityName": "Brunei",
          "line2": "Kampung Kiulap",
          "line1": "6 & 7, Block A, Kompleks Shakirin",
          "careOfName": "",
          "state": "BR",
          "emailAddress": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
          "postalCode": "BE1518",
          "id": "8804188225559"
        },
        {
          "telephoneNumber": "5494492",
          "isoCountryCode": "BN",
          "line3": "GADONG",
          "line4": "8171571",
          "cityName": "BDR SERI BEGAWAN",
          "line2": "KAMPONG RIMBA",
          "line1": "5 SIMPANG 12-32",
          "careOfName": "",
          "state": "BR",
          "emailAddress": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
          "postalCode": "BE3119",
          "id": "8802223521815"
        },
        {
          "telephoneNumber": "5494492",
          "isoCountryCode": "BN",
          "line3": "GADONG",
          "line4": "8171571",
          "cityName": "BDR SERI BEGAWAN",
          "line2": "KAMPONG RIMBA",
          "line1": "5 SIMPANG 12-32",
          "careOfName": "",
          "state": "BR",
          "emailAddress": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
          "postalCode": "BE3119",
          "id": "8802223521815"
        },
        {
          "telephoneNumber": "03-7946 2800",
          "isoCountryCode": "BN",
          "line3": "Bandar Seri Begawan",
          "cityName": "Brunei",
          "line2": "Kampung Kiulap",
          "line1": "6 & 7, Block A, Kompleks Shakirin",
          "careOfName": "",
          "state": "BR",
          "emailAddress": "myhelpdesk@Amway.com",
          "postalCode": "BE1518",
          "id": "8800157073431"
        }
      ],
      "totalOrderValue": 147.5,
      "lynxPaymentChangePaid": 0.0,
      "lynxIsRepair": false,
      "adjustments": [],
      "requestedDeliveryServiceLevel": "walkin",
      "lynxTenure": 0,
      "saleCountryCode": "BN",
      "orderDateTime": "2020-06-25T14:05:56.328+08:00",
      "invoiceSalesAccount": {
        "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
        "accountId": "8055817",
        "lynxPinLevel": "330",
        "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
        "affiliateCode": "100"
      },
      "userAgent": "Suresh Mathiarasu",
      "orderStatus": "PICKUP_COMPLETE",
      "isoCurrencyCode": "BND",
      "fees": [{
        "feeCode": "walkin",
        "feeTaxTotalAmount": 0.0,
        "lynxRefunded": false,
        "feeAmount": 0.0,
        "feeTaxDetails": [{
          "taxAmount": 0.0,
          "taxCode": "BN_NO_SCOPE_VAT_SALES"
        }]
      }],
      "bonusPeriod": "202006",
      "orderingPartyId": "40986385",
      "lynxPayerPartyId": "40986385",
      "salesChannelCode": "Point of Sale",
      "lynxIsEpp": false,
      "lynxPayerPartyName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP",
      "lynxDemandLocationName": "BN",
      "lynxDeliveryType": "pis",
      "paymentSalesAccount": {
        "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
        "accountId": "8055817",
        "lynxPinLevel": "330",
        "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
        "affiliateCode": "100"
      },
      "orderPriceList": "AmwayDefaultABOPriceGroup",
      "lynxVolumePartyId": "40986385",
      "lynxHasSopEntries": false,
      "orderLines": [{
        "linePrice": 147.5,
        "itemType": "AmwayVariantProduct",
        "itemBV": 29.5,
        "lynxBmCode": [],
        "lynxInvoiceNumber": "130099000",
        "lynxLineAdjustedPV": 0.0,
        "shippedQuantity": 5,
        "lineStatus": "OPEN",
        "lynxProductSerialNumber": [],
        "lineUnitOfMeasure": "EA",
        "allocatedQuantity": 5,
        "linePVAmount": 95.0,
        "fulfillments": [{
          "fulfillmentLocation": "T45",
          "fulfilledItemRevision": "",
          "fulfilledSKU": "115383D",
          "uniqueFulfillmentID": "100000002118",
          "fulfilledBaseItemId": "115383D",
          "fulfilledDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:57.167+08:00",
          "fulfilledItemLot": "",
          "fulfilledQuantity": 5
        }],
        "actualShipDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:57.167+08:00",
        "lastUpdateDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:56.985+08:00",
        "lynxBillingAddressReference": "8802223521815",
        "cancelledQuantity": 0,
        "lynxBaseItemId": "115383D",
        "demandLocation": "T45",
        "backorderedQuantity": 0,
        "taxNotRequired": false,
        "lynxLineFulfillmentStatus": "SHIPPED",
        "lynxBirTaxPerUnit": 0.0,
        "pickupAddressReference": "8804188225559",
        "unallocatedQuantity": 0,
        "pendingQuantity": 0,
        "itemABOPrice": 29.5,
        "lineTaxTotalAmount": 0.0,
        "lynxIsSopLine": false,
        "lynxWasBackorder": false,
        "itemSuggestedRetailPrice": 37.0,
        "lineTotalValue": 147.5,
        "baseItemId": "115383D",
        "lynxMasterCode": [],
        "itemDescription": "ARTISTRY SIGNATURE COLOR Lipstick - Daring Red (06) (3.8g)",
        "lineTaxDetails": [{
          "taxAmount": 0.0,
          "taxCode": "BN_NO_SCOPE_VAT_SALES"
        }],
        "shipAddressReference": "8804188225559",
        "lynxPickupAddressName": "BN",
        "lynxIsSopEntry": false,
        "lynxBirAcknowledgementResetCounter": "1",
        "lynxLineAdjustedBV": 0.0,
        "orderedQuantity": 5,
        "itemListPrice": 29.5,
        "fulfillmentType": "walkin",
        "returnedQuantity": 0,
        "actualDeliveryDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:57.167+08:00",
        "orderLineId": 0,
        "itemPV": 19.0,
        "lineBVAmount": 147.5
      }],
      "lynxFulfillmentAddressReference": "8800157073431",
      "cashierBatchId": "amwaybrunei-AM-BN-BN-T45-MY020394-1593058911313",
      "lynxOrderingPartyName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP",
      "totalBVAmount": 147.5,
      "lynxVolumeTransactions": [{
        "lynxInterfaceType": "ORDERS",
        "lynxInterfaceAttribute": "positive",
        "lynxPointValue": 95.0,
        "lynxTransactionTime": "2020-06-25T14:05:56.981+08:00",
        "lynxStatus": "CREATED",
        "lynxTransactionType": "ORDER",
        "lynxBonusPeriod": "202006",
        "lynxBusinessValue": 147.5
      }],
      "volumeSalesAccount": {
        "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
        "accountId": "8055817",
        "lynxPinLevel": "330",
        "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
        "affiliateCode": "100"
      },
      "taxDetails": [{
        "taxAmount": 0.0,
        "taxCode": "BN_NO_SCOPE_VAT_SALES"
      }],
      "lynxUserType": "AmwayBusinessNature_1",
      "lynxPaymentTenderedAmount": 147.5,
      "lynxVolumePartyName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP",
      "lynxOrderCreatedBy": "MY020394",
      "lynxOms": "Hybris",
      "orderForSalesAccount": {
        "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
        "accountId": "8055817",
        "lynxPinLevel": "330",
        "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
        "affiliateCode": "100"
      },
      "lynxPaymentInstalmentType": "PIF",
      "lynxMemberPoints": 0.0,
      "lynxContactPhone": "5494492",
      "totalPVAmount": 95.0,
      "inventoryTransactionRequired": true,
      "lynxIsEventBooking": false,
      "lynxBirCashierId": "MY020394",
      "refunds": [],
      "invoiceWithConsignmentRequired": false,
      "orderPeriod": "202006",
      "orderingSalesAccount": {
        "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
        "accountId": "8055817",
        "lynxPinLevel": "330",
        "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
        "affiliateCode": "100"
      },
      "lynxContactEmailId": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
      "amwaySalesEntity": "780",
      "paymentStatus": "PAID",
      "storefront": "amwaybrunei",
      "lynxPaymentType": "PIF",
      "salesOrderId": "7100029639",
      "lynxOrderCategory": "selfOrder",
      "payments": [{
        "verificationDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:54.453+08:00",
        "lynxIsConnectedFlow": false,
        "paymentLocation": "T45",
        "lynxPaymentProcessedBy": "8055817",
        "paymentStatus": "ACCEPTED",
        "terminalId": "MY020394",
        "paymentReferenceId": "TXN-1593065154321",
        "payerSalesAccount": {
          "accountId": "8055817",
          "lynxPinLevel": "330",
          "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
          "affiliateCode": "100"
        },
        "paymentDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:54.456+08:00",
        "isoCurrencyCode": "BND",
        "lynxPaymentInformation": "",
        "paymentId": "831122002_4e7c1945-b49d-4c86-a0b8-a05b0cb805fa",
        "paymentValue": 147.5,
        "paymentMethod": "cash",
        "merchantId": "amway"
      }],
      "shipToSalesAccount": {
        "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
        "accountId": "8055817",
        "lynxPinLevel": "330",
        "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
        "affiliateCode": "100"
      },
      "totalABORetailProfit": 0.0,
      "totalTaxAmount": 0.0,
      "lynxOrderType": "NORMAL_ORDER",
      "lynxComments": []
    }
  }
]



/* Get Result */
function getResult() {
  order = $("#order").val() || '';
  accountId = $("#accountId").val() || '';

  var result = [],
    i;

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  //here you need to get data->entity->salesOrderId ,Also for accountId it is under eventInfo
   if (data[i].entity.salesOrderId  === order ||data[i].eventInfo.accountId === accountId )  {
   
      result.push(data[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
};

$('#submit').click(function() {
//console.log("in")
  var output = getResult();
  var html = '';
  $.each(output, function(key, value) {
  //changes made accordingly
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td>' + value.entity.salesOrderId + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + value.eventInfo.accountId + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + value.eventInfo.eventType + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + value.entity.orderDateTime + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' +  value.entity.orderStatus + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' +  value.entity.totalPVAmount + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' +  value.entity.totalBVAmount + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' +  value.entity.totalOrderValue + '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
  });
 
  $('table tbody').html(html);
});
```

and Index page is like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Order Search</title>
<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid px-5">
    <div class="col-12 mt-5">

        <h1>Order Enquiry</h1>
        <form>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <p><b>Country</b></P>
                     <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
                        <option class="hidden" selected disabled>Choose</option>
                        <option>Malaysia</option>
                        <option>Vietnam</option>
                        <option>Philippines</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            
                <div class="col-2">
                    <p><b>Order Type</b></P>
                    <select class="form-control" name="name" id="email">
                         <option class="hidden" selected disabled>Choose</option>
                         <option>Sales order</option>
                         <option>Sales Return</option>
                    </select>
                 </div>
            
                 <div class="col-2">
                    <p><b>Order No.</b></p>
                    <input type="number" name="order" id="order" class="form-control">
                 </div>
          
                <div class="col-2.5">
                    <p><b>From Date</b></p>
                    <input type="datetime-local" name="date" id="date" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="col-2.5">
                    <p><b>To Date</b></p>
                    <input type="datetime-local" name="date" id="date" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            
                <div class="col-2">
                    <p><b>ABO NO</b></p>
                    <input type="text" name="accountId" id="accountId" class="form-control">
                </div>
 

                 <div class="col-3">
                    <p><b>Account Type</b></P>
                    <select class="form-control" name="name" id="account">
                        <option class="hidden" selected disabled>Choose</option>
                        <option>Payment Sales Account</option>
                        <option>Volume Sales Account</option>
                        <option>Invoice Sales Account</option>
                        <option>Ship to Sales Account</option>
                        <option>Ordering Sales Account</option>
                        <option>Order to Sales Account</option>
                    </select>
                 </div>
               
               
                <div class="col-3">
                    <br>
                    <p><b></b></P>
                    <p><b></b></P>
                    <p><input id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-1" value="Submit">
                    <input type="reset" id="reset1" value="Reset" class="btn btn-secondary mt-1"></p>
                </div>
            
        
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
    
    
    
 <div class="container-fluid px-0">
       
     <div class="row col-md-12 col-md-offset-2 custyle">
        <table class="table table-striped custab">
            <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Order No</th>
                    <th>ABO NO</th>
                    <th>order Type</th>
                    <th>order Date</th>
                    <th>order status</th>
                    <th>Total PV</th>
                    <th>Total BV</th>
                    <th>Total Amount</th>
                
                 </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              
            </tbody>    
               
                
        </table>
        
     </div>

 </div>

</form>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\BINU\Desktop\final 2\script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

can someone please help to solve this? basically the requirement is there should be a selector button in each records, once click on selector, the particular payload (entire) should appear

Comment: Please provide additional info like which particular DIV you want shown/hidden after clicking which particular button/div in your HTML code.

Comment: if you run my code, you can see i get 5  2 outputs.. once i click on each output row, then i should see each payload. is it possible?